# How to test iOS 5.0 app on Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I can change my deployment target from 3.0 to 4.3 and test that my application is compatible with all these versions but how can I test if my application is compatible with all versions including iOS 5.0? Any idea regarding the same? Also note that I have iPhone 3GS with iOS 4.0.2 and need to test in iOS 5.0. Hope to get a good help. Thanks.

Comment: Why cant you test through the simulator?

Comment: How can I test on iOS 5 simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, you'll need to get a device that has iOS 5 installed. Without that, you can only test this in the iOS 5 simulator.

Also note that changing the deployment target is not enough to test if your app is compatible with that OS version. Basically, this just means that you *promise* that it'll run from this version upwards, but it doesn't enforce that you don't use any APIs that might not be available there.

Comment: Thanks omz for a nice explanation, but can you do me a favor by explaining how to test in iOS 5 simulator? As when I click on simulator and go to Hardware->Version,it shows me 4.3.2 available. What should I do for that?

Comment: @Sarah What version of Xcode are you using? You will need one that comes packaged with iOS 5.

Comment: Oh...I am using Xcode 4.2. Do I need to upgrade to 4.3 or any other?

Comment: Then you need to change that. Basically the base sdk should always be the latest version that you support. The deployment target specifies the oldest version that you support. And yes, you can still run your app on a 4.3 device with the base sdk set to 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

I you wanna do it properly, you will have to get every device there is, with every version you want to support ... that is, imho, overkill. I just test my Apps on the 4.3 and 5.0 Simulator in XCode and on my 5.0 iPhone 4. And have not had any problems with that 'til now.

BTW you should update your 3GS to 5.0.1.

Comment: Nah, don't update your 3GS to 5.0.1. Keep it with an old OS, as a lot of users don't upgrade and its good to test old devices with an old OS. Just buy a new phone with 5.0.1.

Comment: @Sarah, maybe you have an iPhone 3G (not the 3GS) - you can only upgrade to 4.2.1

Comment: @bandejapaisa with the adaption rate of iOS 5 though, i think it is better to test the newest version on the device, and many independent devs just can not afford buying a second iPhone for testing ... an iPod touch might be a considerable alternative though

Comment: No,it is iPhone 3gs. Also how can I test in ios5 simulator? check the comment below

Comment: @Ahti Yup - they are expensive. It all depends on your user base. I'm currently working on a app with 500,000 users, and for example 3% use a handset less than 3GS, seems a small percent... but 15,000 users. If you're not going to test iOS 4 on a device before you release - then I wouldn't support it. Don't rely on the simulator. I'd rather release a tested product than gamble and try and grab more users that could potentially effect the reputation of my app if it was buggy on old versions. minor OS version that only hap

Answer (score 0):

To test in the simulator with iOS5, you can set the OS version with the `Version` submenu of the simulator's `Hardware` menu.

Comment: The iOS simulator is a Macintosh application.  When you run it, it has a menu bar at the top like any other application including a `Hardware` menu.

Comment: I tried to do that but there is only one option available stating 4.3.2(8HS)

Comment: Have you got your base SDK and deployemnt target set correctly?  Base should be iOS 5 and target should be the earliest level you support.

Comment: My base sdk is latest iOS(4.3) and deployment target is 4.0.2

Comment: @Sarah:  you haven't got the iOS 5 SDK installed for some reason then.